# Is $C(A)+C(B)=C(A+B)$, if $C(A)\cap C(B)= \{0\}\,$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is $C(A)+C(B)=C(A+B)$, if $C(A)\cap C(B)= \{0\}?$ where $C(A)$ denotes the column space of $A$.

It's true that, $\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}\rank(A+B)=\rank(A)+\rank(B),$ if $C(A)\cap C(B)= \{0\}$ so, I guess that may be the above statement is true.So, I tried to prove it, but can't make a reasonable progress.
So, any hints or counterexample?

Edited: As pointed out the above statement is not true.Then, under what conditions the above statement is true?

Comment: What is meant by $\theta$ here? Did you mean $\emptyset$? Also, your assertion that rank(A+B)=rank(A)+rank(B) is not true. Consider the fact that $0=A+(-A)$ for any matrix $A$ for an easy counterexample

Comment: @pwerth I think he means that $\operatorname{rank}(A + B) = \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$ if $C(A) \cap C(B) = \{0\}$

Comment: Yeah!I edited that.

Comment: Even so, actually, the statement doesn't hold.  For instance, with
$$
A = \pmatrix{1\\0}, B = \pmatrix{0\\1}
$$
the column spaces are complimentary but $A + B$ has rank $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $C(A) \cap C(B) = \{0\}$, it is not necessarily true that $\operatorname{rank}(A+B) = \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$, or that $C(A+B) = C(A) + C(B)$.

As a counterexample for both of these, consider the matrices
$$
A = \pmatrix{1\\0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{0\\1}
$$
It is true, however, that $C(A+B) \subset C(A) + C(B)$, and $\operatorname{rank}(A+B) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$.

Comment: Then, under what conditions the given statement is true? i.e. $C(A)+C(B)=C(A+B)$

Comment: Can you give a bit more context?  Is there a specific situation where you're expecting this situation to hold?  Why are you looking for matrices satisfying this condition in the first place?